# Magento 2.2.8 and Paypal error 500

Tags: paypal, magento2.2.2, paypal-payflow-pro

I have some problem since several month, with Google Chrome Browser, when someone want to make a checkout, paypal return us an error 500.  The error given are "POST [lang]/paypal/transparent/response/ HTTP/1.1" 500.

After some tests, i don't get this error with Firefox, Opera or Microsoft Egde, i've found some hint on google, but nothing work. My current Magento version are 2.2.8. I know it's a bit old.
Someone get this problem and found a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help.Seems a patch is available and fix in 2.3.5
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26840